# Why are these deferred tasks not being executed in the order in which they were added?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, twilio

I'm using Twilio to send sms's with appengine. Twilio doesn't accept sms's longer than 160 characters so I have to split them. I am splitting the sms's and sending them as follows:

```
def send_sms_via_twilio(mobile_number, message_text):
    client = TwilioRestClient(twilio_account_sid , twilio_auth_token)
    message = client.sms.messages.create(to=mobile_number, from_=my_twilio_number, body=message_text)

split_list = split_sms(long_message)
for each_message in split_list:
    send_sms_via_twilio(each_message)
```

However I found that the order of sending varied. For example sometimes I'd recieve message 2/5 then 1/5 then 4/5 etc and other times the order would be correct. The order of the split_list is definately correct. To overcome the incorrect order of the sms's I tried

```
for each_message in split_list:
    deferred.defer(send_sms_via_twilio, each_message, _countdown=1)
```

However I encountered the same problem. I then tried

```
for each_message in split_list:
    deferred.defer(send_sms_via_twilio, each_message, _countdown=1, _queue="send-text-message")
```

and defined my queue as

```
- name: send-text-message
  rate: 1/s
  bucket_size: 10
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  retry_parameters:   
    task_retry_limit: 5
```

Thinking that the issue was concurrency (running in python27) and that if I limited max_concurrent_requests this issue would be solved. However the issue is still present i.e. the texts still get sent in the wrong order. I checked the logs but couldnt see any notification of task failure - they just seem to be executing in the wrong order.

Is there something I am missing? How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the SMS messaging (specifically the underlying protocols like SMPP) are asynchronous by definition. It means there is no way you can specify the order of **distinct** SMS messages.

There **is** a way to specify the order of SMS packets by using the UDH ([user defined headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS)) in the binary body of those messages. But this works only for long SMS messages -- those that are too long to be sent in one message. For example, if your msg exceeds 160 GSM-7 characters or 80 UTF-16 characters it will be send as more than one message with UDH.

In that case the mobile phone won't show message parts as they arrive. It will collect them in memory until the last one comes and then assembles them in the right order. For the end user this is just a message longer than usual and you don't have to write "1/3", "2/3", ... in the message.

Disclaimer: I work for a company that enables you to send and receive both multiple binary messages with user-specified headers (UDH) and/or standard long messages.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Twilio do specify that they are unable to send "long" sms's, and require that the user only sends them an sms that is less than 161 characters. It is for this reason that I manually split the long sms's and am attempting to send the split sms's to Twilio separately and in the order I want the user to receive them. I can see that the fault is not Twilio's but rather in the appengine process because when I examine the logs the messages are sent to Twilio in the incorrect order, rather than the order that I send them to the queue (in the final example).

Comment: Even if the order in AppEngine logs are correct -- you still can't be sure that the messages would have arrived on the mobile phone. Mobile operators do have their own blocks, queues and priorities and it is very common that messages come in wrong order. There is only one way to do that right -- send the first message, wait for delivery report, send seconds message, wait for delivery, ... and so on. But this is slow for the end user.

Comment: Hi Pizz, I've read about this very thing in the Twilio docs, and do believe you. However I figure that if I get appengine to execute the tasks in the correct order, I at least stack the deck in my favor.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not tied to Twilio try using [SMSified](http://smsified.com/).  They automatically split the message for you, insure it is in the correct order, and add "1/2, 2/2..." to the end of the message. In other words you just send the complete message to their REST API, no matter the length, and they handle the rest. Since they also use a REST API you can continue to use Python.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but SMSified is currently US only. My app is UK based, but needs a service that will play nice with as much of Europe as possible...

Comment: How about http://www.aspsms.com/? Acts globally. I have used it and work well. Downside is that message is charged although it's not delivered. They have ability to send multi-part SMS. Doc is: http://www.aspsms.com/documentation/, find there text "SendTextSMS".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That pricing structure looks pretty complicated. And a SOAP API - I've not seem one of those in a while! I'm persisting with Appengine/Twilio for now, but I may be forced to look elsewhere if these issues don't clear up soon.